# Strange issue - mouse click in popup is getting captured by control underneath

Tags: wpf

I'm displaying a `Popup` in response to a button click (`popup.IsOpen = true;`). The popup contains a ComboBox, and when I click an item in the combobox, one of the things the SelectionChanged event does is to hide the popup.

The Popup appears over a `DataGrid` that I also have on my page, and I'm finding that the mouse-click on the combobox is also being picked up by a MouseUp event that I've got on the DataGrid. Any idea what's going on?

Answer (score 3):

The [`MouseUp`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.mouseup.aspx) Event has a routing strategy of type `Bubbling`. Events that use this type of strategy get passed up the chain to parent controls. Since the `Popup` is a child of the `DataGrid`, the event will "bubble" up to the `DataGrid`. If you would rather the event not bubble, you can try using [`PreviewMouseUp`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.previewmouseup.aspx), which has a `Tunneling` routing strategy, and will "tunnel" down the chain to child controls. Here is a decent [`overview`](http://www.kirupa.com/net/event_bubbling_tunneling.htm) of `Routing Strategies`.

Comment: I've tried both MouseUp and PreviewMouseUp on the DataGrid, but with no success. Strangely, the popup also includes a button and I don't get a problem with that - only when clicking the combobox.

Comment: @AndrewStephens: Hmm, that's weird... I experimented a bit on my own and my datagrid's MouseUp was not getting fired on the ComboBox click... the PreviewMouseUp event was firing though (I would've thought it would be the other way around). I also hid the popup when an item was selected. So I can't re-create the problem... interested in posting some code?

Answer (score 0):

I've hit the same issue. Oddly, it doesn't happen when the code is run in the debugger - it only happens in the release version. It really seems to be a bug in WPF. Trying to catch the click and set the event to handled doesn't work.

My workaround is to, when the popup opens, to tell the control underneath to ignore the click.